# If $\sum _{i=1}^{\infty} d(x_i,x_{i+1}) < \infty $ then $x_n$ is a Cauchy sequence.

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

Let $(x_n)$ is a Cauchy sequence in a Metric space. If $\sum _{i=1}^{\infty} d(x_i,x_{i+1}) < \infty $  then $x_n$ is a Cauchy sequence.

What about the converse ?
If it is false any counter example?

Comment: No the converse is false.  Perhaps you can find a real sequence that converges to $0$ (say, alternately positive and negative) such that adjacent terms only decrease like $d(x_n,x_{n+1}) = 1/n$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $x_n=\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{(-1)^k}{k}$, then $(x_n)$ is a Cauchy sequence because it converges toward $-\ln 2$. But
$$ d(x_n,x_{n+1})=\frac{1}{n+1} $$
and thus $\sum d(x_n,x_{n+1})=\infty$.

Comment: Did you mean $= + \infty$?

Comment: Yes you're right

Comment: Well, $d(x_n,x_{n+1})=|x_n-x_{n+1}|=\frac{1}{n+1}$, what you say works with $x_n=\frac{(-1)^n}{n}$.

Comment: Yes sorry, for some reason I completely obliterated that $x_n$ was the series partial sum and not the term of that series. Maybe naming it $S_n$ would avoid the confusion others may have too.

Comment: I used the same notations as in the question.